# Why does composable call twice during passing data between two screen

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-navigation

I have an Issue while passing data between two screen. Currently log called twice from below code

```
        composable(Screens.VisionBoardNameChooserScreen.route) {
            userViewModel.getUserNameUseCase()
            val userName = userViewModel.fetchUserName.collectAsState()

            VisionBoardNameChooserScreen(userName, submitVisionBoard = { boardName ->
                visionBoardNameViewModel.saveBoard(
                    BoardData(
                        visionBoardName = boardName
                    )
                )
                navController.navigate(Screens.AddSectionScreen.route + "/$boardName")
            }, onBackPressClicked = {
                navController.popBackStack()
            })

        }

        composable(Screens.AddSectionScreen.route + "/{boardName}") {navBackStack ->

            val boardName = navBackStack.arguments?.getString("boardName")
            Log.i("NAVTAG", "VisionBoardNavigation: $boardName")

            AddSectionScreen(onBackPressClicked = {
                navController.popBackStack()
            }, submitSection = {

                // TODO: Add Data Into Database and Then Redirect To Next Screen

                navController.navigate(Screens.HomeScreen.route)
            })
        }
```

Here is My Logcat
[image]

Answer (score 0):

**In jetpack compose any composable recomposes multiple times on the screen**. And if you are performing some work inside the navigation composable then it also called multiple times as `Log` does in your case. To avoid this you can do that particular work inside `LaunchedEffect` and then pass the data in the Screen. Composable cannot be created inside `LaunchedEffect` and hence, by this way you can save multiple calls but screen will recompose with the provide data.

**Example:**
Replace your line `Log.i("NAVTAG", "VisionBoardNavigation: $boardName")` with

```
// Pass any value as the keys
LaunchedEffect(key1 = true) {
    Log.i("NAVTAG", "VisionBoardNavigation: $boardName")
}
```

The `LaunchedEffect` will only called again if the provided keys(`true` in our case) are changed. As we can also pass multiple keys as the parameter. And in our case `true` is not changing so it will just run once. That's how you can do single time task using `LaunchedEffect`.