# Composable Keeps recomposing - Loading Dialog Keeps Updating Multiple Times

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, recompose

**VisionBoardNameViewModel**

I'm experiencing an issue where a ProgressDialog that displays loading information is persistently shown due to frequent recomposition of our Composable UI. This behavior is likely caused by how I manage and update data in our ViewModel and UseCase layers.

How can I solve this? Here is my code.

```kotlin
@HiltViewModel
class VisionBoardNameViewModel @Inject constructor(
        val getLastBoardDataUseCase: GetLastBoardDataUseCase
) : ViewModel() {
    
       
        private val _boardDataUiState = MutableStateFlow(BoardDataUiState())
        val boardDataUiState: Flow<BoardDataUiState> = _boardDataUiState.asStateFlow()
   
    
        fun getLastBoardData() = viewModelScope.launch {
    
            getLastBoardDataUseCase().collectLatest { response ->
                when (response) {
                    is Resource.Success -> {
                        _boardDataUiState.update { currentState ->
                            currentState.copy(boardData = response.data, isLoading = false)
                        }
                    }
    
                    is Resource.Failure -> {
                        _boardDataUiState.update { currentState ->
                            currentState.copy(error = response.message, isLoading = false)
                        }
                    }
    
                    is Resource.Loading -> {
                        _boardDataUiState.update { currentState ->
                            currentState.copy(isLoading = true)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
}
```

**GetLastBoardDataUseCase**

```kotlin
class GetLastBoardDataUseCase @Inject constructor(
        private val boardDataRepository: BoardDataRepository
) {
    
        operator fun invoke(): Flow<Resource<BoardData>> = flow {
            emit(Resource.Loading())
            try {
                emit(Resource.Success(boardDataRepository.getBoardList().first()))
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                emit(Resource.Failure(e.message.toString()))
            }
        }
}
```

**VisionBoardNavigation**

```kotlin
@Composable
fun VisionBoardNavigation(navController: NavHostController) {
    
    
       NavHost(
            navController = navController,
            startDestination = Screens.HomeScreen.route
        ) {
          
            composable(Screens.HomeScreen.route) { navBackStack ->
                
                    val boardName = navBackStack.arguments?.getString("boardName")
                    val boardUId = navBackStack.arguments?.getInt("boardUId")
    
                    boardUId?.let { homeViewModel.getBoardSectionList(it) }
    
                    val homeUiState by homeViewModel.sectionList.collectAsState()
    
                    HomeScreen(boardName.toString(), homeUiState)
                
            }
        }   
}
```

```kotlin
@Composable
fun HomeScreen(boardName: String = "Hey There", homeUiState: HomeScreenUIState) {

    var showLoading by remember {
        mutableStateOf(false)
    }

    LaunchedEffect(key1 = homeUiState.loading, block = {
        showLoading = homeUiState.loading
    })

    if (showLoading) {
        Dialog(
            onDismissRequest = { },
            DialogProperties(dismissOnBackPress = false, dismissOnClickOutside = false)
        ) {
            Box(
                contentAlignment = Alignment.Center,
                modifier = Modifier
                    .size(100.dp)
                    .background(White, shape = RoundedCornerShape(16.dp))
            ) {
                CircularProgressIndicator()
            }
        }
    }
    
} {

}
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can check my solution which explains multiple recomposition and use of `LaunchedEffect` in jetpack compose. https://stackoverflow.com/a/76969294/14972910

In this case `showLoading` variable is `remebered` and set to `true` in `HomeScreen` composable and so that whenever the `HomeScreen` recomposes then it will also recompose the dialog as the `showLoading` is `true`.

So you have to restrict `HomeScreen` for recomposition and you can use `LaunchedEffect` for that in the `NavHost`.

Comment: As per your reference I have already Implemented LaunchedEffected in my HomeScreen

Comment: @PratikFagadiya I have edited my solution so check once again.

Comment: I have already tried that method where I were implemented LaunchedEfefct Inside My Navhost instead of HomeScreen But unfortunately it doesn't work for me

Comment: @PratikFagadiya Try to pass `homeUiState.loading` as a parameter to `HomeScreen` composable and then use it this will also reduce unwanted variables.

Answer (score 0):

Try omitting the `showLoading` remember and also the `LaunchedEffect` block and instead directly check `homeUiState.loading` to change visibility of the `CircularProgressIndicator`.

```
    if (homeUiState.loading) {
        // circular progress composable
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
val showLoading by remember(homeUiState) {
  derivedStateOf { homeUiState.loading }
}
```

Try it like this and see if it works. If you want to learn more about the concept check this [great article](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/jetpack-compose-when-should-i-use-derivedstateof-63ce7954c11b).